# Как правильно проверить является json-объект валидным для java-класса или нет?

Tags: java, json, юнит-тесты

Как правильно проверить является json-объект валидным для java-класса или нет?

Есть класс java, который описывает структуру сообщения.
и есть json, который нужно проверять на соответствие структуре описанной в java...

Как лучше написать на это UnitTest?

(ответ хотелось бы в виде java кода)

Comment: Что такое json-строки? Первый раз такое читаю.

Comment: Запарсить и поймать эксепшн. Как бы, если все получилось - то все ок, не получилось - не ок. Или что-то другое надо?

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko Что вы имеете ввиду *запарсить*? Надо писать свой парсер, который выдоет свой *эксепшн*, который вы будете потом ловить?

Comment: Использовать готовый. Зачем свой писать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте какую-то библиотеку(например Jackson), скормите его Java(Например пошлите AJAX запрос с JS) и перехватите исключение(если его не будет, то все валидно, если будет. то вы сами все увидите). Если используете Spring, то можете перехватить с помощью @ExceptionHandler.

Comment: спасибо за ответ... но вопрос именно о том, как проверить такой код... Смысла нет в юнит тесте если код будет такой же как в тестируемом им коде...